# Access or inject QuarkusTestResource in the actual test?

Tags: quarkus

I have a unit test annotated with @QuarkusTestResource that setups a Wiremock for an internal rest client. Can I inject the actual resource (the class implementing QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager) into the test somehow so I can access the Wiremock server to perform verifications on it?

Comment: There's a example for that in the documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#altering-the-test-class

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that in the documentation! Worth to note that the annotation needs Retention = RUNTIME